# Mnemonic for platykurtic and leptokurtic

Tags: soft-question, distribution-tails

I keep confusing terms leptokurtic and platykurtic. Is there a good mnemonic to help remember which is which?

"Lepto" means "little", "platy" means "flat", and both are equally unrelated to thickness of a tail. It also does not help that "lepto" (small) means excess *positive* kurtosis (had to look it up, btw. Again.)

Comment: Maybe it helps to know a platypus is a "flat-foot".

Comment: @Prometheus, so if tails of a distribution are kind of its feet, left and right, then flat feet means not too much of distribution is there, something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You only need a mnemonic for one of them, right? For "platy-" think of a plain or plateau or platyhelminthes or platypus or platter. Or just think of the word **flat**--which sounds more like "flat" to you, platy or lepto?

Comment: my difficulty is that "lepto" is "little" and "platy" is "flat" and they are pretty much same thing in my mind

Comment: little sucks, i mean when have you heard little is good, flat however is awesome.

Comment: Well, try to think of them as "slender" and "broad", or "thin" and "fat".

Comment: leptos doesn't mean "little". It's "thin, skinny, thin". A tall skinny person is leptos.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few years old, but one I've come up with (not sure if original) is that a leptokurtic distribution has a big "peak" to **lepto** (leap over) and that a platykurtic distribution is a plateau and thus nothing or is something very small to jump over.

Yeah, it's dumb, but it works.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: While "lepto" means positive excess kurtosis, it does not imply "high peak." The peak could be flat, bimodal, sinusoidal, anything at all: take a distribution with any shape peak whatsoever, and mix it with a much wider distribution with small mixing p, and the resulting distribution will have the same shape of peak as the original, but very high kurtosis. Similarly, "platy" means negative excess kurtosis, but does not imply flat-topped or lowly-peaked. The beta(.5,1) distribution, has negative excess kurtosis but an infinite peak. Kurtosis measures outlier potential, not the peak.